# Linear programming simplex method pivot points illogical?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

so I'm struggling to find how the pivot points were found in the following optimization problem:
$$Minimize\ z = a + b + c$$
$$Subject\ to:$$
$$a - b - c ≤ 0$$
$$a + b + c ≥ 4$$ 
$$a + b - c = 2$$ 
$$a, b ≥ 0$$

I got the problem into this form:
$$Maximize\ z* + a + b + c’ – c’’ = 0$$
Such that $c = c' - c''$ and $z*=-z$
$$Subject\ to:$$
$$a – b – c’ – c’’ + S_1 = 0$$
$$a + b + c’ – c’’ – L_1 + A_1 = 4$$
$$a + b – c’ – c’’ + A_2 = 2$$
$$a, b, c’, c’’, S_1, L_1, A_1, A_2 ≥ 0$$
With the first tableu being:

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
           & a & b & c' & c'' & S_1 & L_1 & A_1 & A_2 &    \\ \hline
           & 1 &-1 &-1  &-1   & 1   &  0  & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
           & 1 & 1 & 1  &-1   & 0   & -1  & 1   & 0   & 4   \\
           & 1 & 1 &-1  &-1   & 0   &  0  & 0   & 1   & 2   \\ \hline
           & 1 & 1 & 1  &-1   & 0   &  0  & 0   & 0   & 0
\end{array}
The problem is, from here, I got no success (using c'' as pivot column), so I checked a few simplex calculators to see what I was doing wrong, and they seemed to get to the same sort of setup as me, and with the same tableu. However, from there, they took column a as pivot column, which is the most *positive* number? They then got the ratios, and took row 1 as pivot row (ratio of 0), which I guess makes sense?

After creating the second tableu, they took column b as the pivot coulumn (again most positive z number(tied) at 2), **BUT**, then they used row 3, which had a ratio of 1, meanwhile row 1 still had a ratio of 0.

Same sort of scenario with the third and fourth* tableus, achieving a final answer of
$$a=2, b=1, c=1(1-0)$$
$$min z = 4$$

As far as I can tell the answer is right, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how they got the pivot points.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Also, in the final tableu, which is used as the solution, the z row still contains positive and negative numbers, as well as zeros.

Edit 2: Thanks to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142239/how-does-the-simplex-method-handle-test-ratios-with-zeros?rq=1), as far I can tell the zero was not selected in the second and third tableus because the pivot in that case would be nonpositive.

Edit 3: Second, third, and fourth (*whoops there's four) tableus:
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
           & a & b & c' & c'' & S_1 & L_1 & A_1 & A_2 &    \\ \hline
           & 1 &-1 &-1  &-1   & 1   &  0  & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
           & 0 & 2 & 2  & 0   &-1   & -1  & 1   & 0   & 4   \\
           & 0 & 2 & 0  & 0   &-1   &  0  & 0   & 1   & 2   \\ \hline
           & 0 & 2 & 2  & 0   &-1   &  0  & 0   & 0   & 0
\end{array}

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
           & a & b & c' & c'' & S_1 & L_1 & A_1 & A_2 &    \\ \hline
           & 1 & 0 &-1  &-1   & 1/2 &  0  & 0   & 1/2 & 1   \\
           & 0 & 0 & 2  & 0   & 0   & -1  & 1   &-1   & 2   \\
           & 0 & 1 & 0  & 0   &-1/2 &  0  & 0   & 1/2 & 1   \\ \hline
           & 0 & 0 & 2  & 0   & 0   &  0  & 0   &-1   &-2
\end{array}

Final:
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
           & a & b & c' & c'' & S_1 & L_1 & A_1 & A_2 &    \\ \hline
           & 1 & 0 & 0  &-1   & 1/2 &-1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 2   \\
           & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0   & 0   &-1/2 & 1/2 &-1/2 & 1   \\
           & 0 & 1 & 0  & 0   &-1/2 &  0  & 0   & 1/2 & 1   \\ \hline
           & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0   & 0   &  1  &-1   & 0   & -4
\end{array}

**So, to reiterate,** what would cause someone to use a positive z-row entry to determine the pivot column, and what determines whether you've reached the optimal solution? As I thought it was the z-row containing no negative enties. Thanks ^^

Comment: "*However, from there, they took coulumn a as pivot coulumn, which is the most positive number*" That´s true.

Comment: What is the second and third tableau?

Comment: @callculus Added the other tableus. ^^   You say that's true, but what I heard is that you're supposed to always take the most negative z-row value to determine the pivot column?